# how do I get the fixed number of permutation of certain number

Tags: python, permutation

let say I have string number with "323123"
if I want to get the fixed number n digit permutation of "323123".

```
for example if n=3 '323','321'.....'123' <br/>
n=2 then '32',23'.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired output (combinations as single strings) can be obtained like this (for the example case `n = 2`):

```
import itertools as it 

num = "323123"
n = 2
perms = ["".join(el) for el in it.permutations(list(num), n)]
print(perms)
```

Which prints:

```
['32', '33', '31', '32', '33', '23', '23', '21', '22', '23', '33', '32', '31', '32', '33', '13', '12', '13', '12', '13', '23', '22', '23', '21', '23', '33', '32', '33', '31', '32']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from itertools import permutations

string = "323123"
n = 2

perms = list(permutations(string, n))
```

Output:

````
[('3', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('2', '3'), ('2', '3'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '3'), ('3', '2'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '3'), ('2', '2'), ('2', '3'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '3'), ('3', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2')]```
````